# call the class which contains the crawl details and parse function to another class

Tags: python, scrapy

I am pretty new to scrapy. i have a very basic doubt but could not find a solution. 
my code:

```
import os
from boto import log
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess, Crawler
from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.utils import reactor

from testing.items import testingItem
from testing.spiders.MySpider1 import Spider1
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from multiprocessing import Pool
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "MySpider"
a=Spider1()
a.parse()
```

*********The above code is in a seperate page***********

```
import scrapy
from testing.items import testingItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
class Spider1():

 def parse(self, response):

  allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
  start_urls = [ "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
  "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
        ]



for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
          item = testingItem()
          item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
          item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
          item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
          yield item
```

The problem is that i wanna crawl the above mentioned site with the above mentioned parse funtion. I am unable to call the function and crawl without error.

Comment: If you get an error why don't you share it with us? (edit your question and add the error messages to it)

Comment: TypeError: parse() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)     this is my error

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message is clear: you call the `parse` function without the `response` parameter. You need a response to let scrapy parse a site information. If you want to start the spider, you need to call it another way.

The general approach is to start a spider from the command line with

```
scrapy crawl <spider_name>
```

where `<spider_name>` has to be replaced with the name of your spider to start.

The second way is more complicated but it allows you to run scrapy from a script. I guess this is what you want to achieve.

In this case you have to set-up a `CrawlerProcess` and `start()` it:

```
settings = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
process.crawl(Spider1)
process.start()
```

This will start the spider -- and it will process all the sites in the `start_urls` and anything you `Request` in the `parse` function.

Comment: How can I get the return of the spider execution inside the class that called it?